# How to save dymnanic webpage URL to web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

When some one does google search, finds a PDF with the URL for example: www.xyz.com/abc/onetwothree.pdf, then click on that PDF. the web.config will redirect that PDF  to a login page asking for username and password. Once the username and password are validated, the PDF URL will be retrieved from the web.config and shown immediately.

My question is how to save that PDF URL to the web.config,  the PDF URL will be different based on the google keyword search.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why use the Web.config at all? Use standard authentication/authorization and place the PDF in a protected folder? How/why would the URL change based on a keyword search?

Comment: Thank you Irish! (1) various keyword search will find various PDF that has various file name leading to various URL since the URL including file name. (2) we need the user either register or login(if they have registered). Once logged in, the PDF the user googled before shall be shown.

Comment: With standard Identity, once they log in they would be returned to the original request URL. However, do not depend on Google to give your user the correct URL!

Comment: Let me know if it works for you and I'll compose it as an answer below :)